# Can not install openssh-server on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: package-management, ssh, dependencies, 16.04

As a fresh new install of Ubuntu 16.04

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

outputs
[image: sudo apt-get install openssh-server]

Also it is a fress install I could not understand why this happens.

```
dpkg -l openssh\*
```

Output is

[image: dpkg -l openssh]

If canonical upgrades to **1:7.2p2-4** for openssh-server version I think problem will be solved.

Also there is a screen shot of synaptics package manager

[image: Synaptic package manager]

If I mark for upgrade there is a window shows packages to be removed:

[image: Removed]

Any help will be appriciated.

Comment: try to upgrade before : apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y

Comment: Nothing changes.

Comment: I don't remember to have had any issue to install it. Can you give us the output of : dpkg -l openssh\\*

Comment: Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                      Version           Architecture      Description
+++-=========================-=================-=================-========================================================
ii  openssh-client            1:7.2p2-4         amd64             secure shell (SSH) client, for secure access to remote m
un  openssh-server            <none>            <none>            (no description available)

Comment: openssh-client version is higher than openssh-server. Client version is 1:7.2p2-4 but server version is 1:7.2p2-2. If canonical upgrades to 1:7.2p2-4 for server version.

Comment: Please  answer the comments by  edit your topic

Comment: Nothing changed.

Comment: If openssh-server is installed, it should works. Maybe you need to configure your openssh-server (login in root can be disable in the sshd_config file).

Comment: It is not installed. http://storage9.static.itmages.com/i/16/0425/h_1461590099_5321332_d006a9a90b.png

Comment: Maybe an issue with your repository. Try to check them. You can also download the openssh-server by downloading a .deb on the web.

Comment: Thank you for your help but. Downloading .deb file will not help. Cause openssh-client version is higher than the lastest openssh-server version. So openssh-server version should be upgraded.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was getting the exact same error.

In the Software & Updates changing the server from my local country to Main server, and also adding the Canonical Partners from the "Other Software" tab helped installing the openssh-server in my case.
I am not sure which of the two helped.

Comment: Changing servers to  main server has solved all problems. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Try to perform a apt update before :

```
apt-get clean
apt-get update
apt-get install openssh-server
```

I was getting the same error and I didn't need to change the server.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. I fixed it by uninstalling the `openssh-client` and then installing `openssh-server`.

```
sudo apt-get remove openssh-client
sudo apt-get autoclean 
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but nothing from the answers worked for me.
What worked for me is removing the `openssh-client`:

```
apt remove openssh-client
```

Then I succeeded to install the SSH:

```
apt install openssh-server

# verify
systemctl status ssh
```